# AVR Stick Data Logger Usage

Tags: usb, avr, datalogger

Has anyone used this data logger (or similar) with [v-usb](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) to collect data?

http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9147

If so, what is the maximum times per second voltage data can be sent at HID messages? (I can't understand the spec sheets)
And can it work with an ultrasonic rangefinder (or similar) also from sparkfun?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The default firmware sends samples to the host once per second. If you need a faster sample rate, you'll need to write custom firmware (and probably some custom USB HID drivers). The MaxSonar rangefinders, available from spaarkfun or littlebird electronics, have an analog output that's perfect for the AVR stick.

Answer (score 1):

The driver is based on V-USB I would ask at their [forum](http://forums.obdev.at/viewforum.php?f=8) regarding the speed.
As far as the range finder it uses serial communication so you won't be able to read it out directly as a voltage.  You should be able to change the firmware on the usb stick to send the proper serial commands to get a distance reading from the ultrasonic rangefinder though and output that over the USB HID interface.